# background is not going to the foreground with jquery

Tags: jquery, background

My question is: Would be possible to get the background images to the foreground?

I created a mask from an example with the div's z-index to 9000 and the div
containing the form's z-index to 9999

So far that works, but if I use a class with a background image it will not show.

I tested everything on a test page without the mask and it works.
Then I moved the stuff to the page with the mask, and then the background images don't show anymore.

Normal images don't seem to have that problem.

This is [my testpage](http://www.woonbel.nl/testpagina.php)

```
// het tbnote opties menu
    $("#tbnoteopties").click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass("uit").toggleClass("aan");
            $(this).next().toggleClass("expanded").toggleClass("collapsed").slideToggle("normal");
    });
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'd like to help but it's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I was experimenting with masking the background, and bringing the form to the foreground. The background, set in a class, got lost.
This is not the case with images that can be placed. I was wondering why that is. It works now with images, instead off toggling some background

Answer (score 0):

The `z-index` determines the element's stack level. Each element is automatically assigned a z-index based on its context in the document.

`z-index` will only work on elements who have explicitly been assigned a `position` value of `absolute`, `fixed`, or `relative`.

You cannot set the `z-index` of a background image. `z-index` sets the stacking order of an html element.

If you are trying to position a background image that is set by using the `background` or `background-image` css property you will end up positioning the element not the background image in the element.